# Why do an eagle’s feet look ridged?

Tags: ornithology

Why are the knuckles of an eagles toes "ridged"?

(I found these pictures to explain.  One was from PBS and the other is one I found on Pinterest):

[image]

I circled the parts of the toes/feet I meant in red (from [PBS](http://www.pbs.org/wnet/nature/american-eagle-bald-eagles-evolutionary-ancestors/4274/)):

[image]

Comment: Their DNA made them like that.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by baggy. I can't see any bagginess in eagle talons. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Please consider rephrasing your query and hence using alternative terminology -- as of now it is a bit unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Those are just scutes.

Comment: @kmm you should post that as a brief answer.

Comment: @kmm Yeah, you should put it as an answer.  I was able to find information by using that keyword.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bubbly structures on the dorsal sides of the digits are scutes. Birds retained them from their dinosaurian ancestors. Here is a picture of similar structures on an alligator foot:

[image: Alligator foot]

Comment: What purpose do they serve?